# Yosemite 10.10.2 and Java

Tags: java, osx-yosemite

I just upgraded to OS X 10.10.2 and now it seems Java is broken.  Netbeans comes up with a totally blank screen.  PHPStorm and Eclipse come up fine.  However, all three apps have file pickers that don't work.  Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Install Java again. At least that's what I did when it happened with me on a Yosemite upgrade. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Aman said in the comments, just install Java again. It looks like it's a widespread problem.

[Here's a link to get a version from Apple that should work](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572).

[Here's a link to get the JDK from Oracle that should work](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).

You can read more about the issue [here](http://osxdaily.com/2014/10/21/get-java-os-x-yosemite/).

Comment: I did the reinstall but the problem persists.  I'm thinking I may need to reinstall the OS since this occurred right after I upgraded to 10.10.2.  Until then everything worked fine.

Comment: @FloydResler Well from what I've seen online, you're not the only person with problems...and it seemed that the solution is simply to install Java again. is there anything else you want me to add to my answer to make it more complete?

Comment: I suspect that I am having other issues that a Java reinstall won't fix.  Such as the file picker not working properly in native Mac apps and now the DVD player tells me a valid video device could not be found.  Hoping it's a software issue and not hardware!  Thanks for the help.

Comment: its not working in native apps like photoshop or lightroom either.

generally 10.10.2 seems to be a buggy build.